# Combine javascript closures together

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a "host" javascript closure, in which i keep all the common variables i am using over the website

```
var hostFunction = (function () {
    var variableA = $("#variableA");
    var variableB = $("#variableB");

    // some usefull code here
} ());
```

In my website, in another javascript file, i have another closure

```
var childFunction = (function () {
    var changeValue = function () {
        variableA.html("I was changed");
    };

    // other usefull code
} ());
```

How is possible to insert "childFunction" inside "hostFunction" so i can get access to those variables?

What is the best practice of sharing variables across the website but also keeping them inside a scope so they don't conflict with other javascript variables?

Comment: Where do you need access to those variables? Where do you declare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the word `this` for those variables to be seen in other scopes

```
var hostFunction = (function () {
    this.variableA = $("#variableA");
    this.variableB = $("#variableB");

    // some usefull code here
} ());
```

You pass in your host in the constructor of your childFunction like this:

```
var childFunction = (function (myHost) {
    var changeValue = function () {
        myHost.variableA.html("I was changed");
    };

    // other usefull code
} (hostFunction));
```

Comment: The downside of this is that i have to prepend this keyword to all the variables, and i don't think is very "safe"

Answer (score 2):

If any information needs to be shared globally, it is best practice to use namespaces to mitigate the risk of your variables clashing with any others.

[This blog post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) gives a reasonable introduction to namespacing in javascript.

Comment: Yes, javascript namespaces seems the best solution. I found this link, which might be helpful for other users also. [link](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)